# Similar functions operating on the same datastructure

Tags: haskell, code-duplication

I've got a data type of the following form:

```
type Orders                 = [Int]
data Score                  = Score Cost Penalty Penalty
type Trip                   = (Int, Cost, Orders)
type Trips                  = [Trip]
type DaySolution            = (Trips, Trips)
data Solution               = Solution { score         :: Score,
                                         skippedOrders :: Orders,
                                         monday        :: DaySolution,
                                         tuesday       :: DaySolution,
                                         wednesday     :: DaySolution,
                                         thursday      :: DaySolution,
                                         friday        :: DaySolution
                              } deriving(Show)
```

My 'main' datatype is solution. Now I want to implement some genetic/evolutionary algorithm.

This means I have to mutate `Solution`. Most of my mutations will need to operate on individual `trip`'s.

For example, reverse the elements of a `trip`. Or Swap the trips of monday with tuesday. Or even swap the monday trips of solution 1 with the monday trips of solution 2.

For most mutations I need the following steps:

1. I need randomness to determine what `Trip`(s) to mutate.
2. Mutate the `Trips`
3. Return the updated solution

Obviously (2.) would be unique for each mutation function. But (1.) and (3.) are quite similar.

What is a good way of implementing this without having to duplicate steps 1 (and 3) for each mutation function?

Comment: If you need randomness, then an abstraction like [MonadRandom](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.4.1/docs/Control-Monad-Random.html) will be useful. If you need to "mutate" something, then an abstraction like [MonadState](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.1/docs/Control-Monad-State-Class.html) will also be useful. You should include some code which solves your problem, which you believe, in particular, suffers from code duplication.

Comment: @user2407038 Sure the randomness comes from some monad. I don't really need state however. Returning a new solution would be fine for me. But thanks for the tips!

Comment: Have you also looked at [Lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) ? It can be very handy when dealing with complex structures

Comment: Not sure if it helps or not, but I did write ["the weasel program"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_program) in Haskell last year and had to address some of these same issues. [My code is here](https://bitbucket.org/fusiongyro/weasel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Concept: higher order functions

A higher order function is a function that takes as input another function. Without realizing, you have probably used several higher order functions already (like `map` and `foldl`).

Simply use a *higher order* function, something with signature:

```
mutateGeneric :: (Trip -> IO Trip) -> Solution -> IO Solution
```

so here the first argument is a function to mutate a trip, and your `mutateGeneric` function itself generates random numbers, performs a modification based on the function, and then returns the solution. If you do not perform `IO` (for instance because random numbers are generate otherwise), you can simply use:

```
mutateGeneric :: (Trip -> Trip) -> Solution -> Solution
```

## Example

Say you first generate an `int` between `0` and `4` (inclusive) to determine the day, next you mutate both trips of that day, and finally you return the mutated solution.

First we are going to define some utility methods:

```
getDay :: Int -> Solution -> DaySolution
getDay 0 = monday
getDay 1 = tuesday
getDay 2 = wednesday
getDay 3 = thursday
getDay 4 = friday

setDay :: Int -> Solution -> DaySolution -> Solution
setDay 0 s d = s { monday = d }
setDay 1 s d = s { tuesday = d }
setDay 2 s d = s { wednesday = d }
setDay 3 s d = s { thursday = d }
setDay 4 s d = s { friday = d }
```

Then mutation looks like:

```
mutateGeneric modifier solution = do
    di <- randomIO :: IO Int
    tam <- modifier ta
    tbm <- modifier tb
    return $ setDay day solution (tam,tbm)
        where day = mod day 5
              (ta,tb) = getDay day solution
```

and now a modifier could for instance swap the first with the second `Trips` item:

```
swapModifier :: Trips -> IO Trips
swapModifier (a:b:s) = return (b:a:s)
swapModifier x = return x
```

Then finally you can say that your modification heurstic is:

```
heuristic1 :: Solution -> IO Solution
heuristic1 = mutateGeneric swapModifier
```

The point is that you can simply construct another modifier like `swapModifier` and combine it with `mutateGeneric`. Of course the example above is rather simple. Furthermore perhaps you need to update scores and penalties. This you can do in the `mutateGeneric` function.

Comment: Maybe I was overthinking it, but this solution will work nicely. Thanks!